# print and cv2_imshow in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
def ensemble_predict(scheme_model,quality_model,rotate_model,img,y=None):


  quality_labels  = ["blur","sharp","torch"]
  rotate_labels = [0,90,-90,180]
  bgr_labels = ["bgr","rgb"]
  
  scheme_pred = scheme_model.predict(img)[0]
  quality_pred = quality_model.predict(img)[0]
  rotate_pred = rotate_model.predict(img)[0]
  cv2_imshow(cv2.resize(img[0]*255,(256,256)))
  
  p = scheme_pred
  scheme_pred = 0 if scheme_pred < 0.5 else 1 
  print("Predict BGR or RGB:", bgr_labels[scheme_pred], ", p:",p[0])
  print("Predict quality:", quality_labels[np.argmax(quality_pred)], ", p:", quality_pred[np.argmax(quality_pred)])
  print("Predict rotation:" ,rotate_labels[np.argmax(rotate_pred)], ", p:", rotate_pred[np.argmax(rotate_pred)])
  
  print()
  if y is not None:
    q_l = quality_labels[y[0]]
    r_l = rotate_labels[y[1]]
    b_l = bgr_labels[y[2]]
    print("True BGR or RGB:", b_l)
    print("True quality:", q_l)
    print("True rotation:" ,r_l)
  print()
  print()
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeBOJ.png)

I work in google colab, how can I make a print to the right of the image that I output via cv2_imshow
I have attached the sample code, I am glad to see the solution, but I am also ready to apply an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def ensemble_predict(scheme_model,quality_model,rotate_model,img,y=None):


  quality_labels  = ["blur","sharp","torch"]
  rotate_labels = [0,90,-90,180]
  bgr_labels = ["bgr","rgb"]
  
  scheme_pred = scheme_model.predict(img)[0]
  quality_pred = quality_model.predict(img)[0]
  rotate_pred = rotate_model.predict(img)[0]
  cv2_imshow(cv2.resize(img[0]*255,(256,256)))
  print("",end='')
  p = scheme_pred
  scheme_pred = 0 if scheme_pred < 0.5 else 1 
  print("\t Predict BGR or RGB:", bgr_labels[scheme_pred], ", p:",p[0],end='')
  print("\t Predict quality:", quality_labels[np.argmax(quality_pred)], ", p:", quality_pred[np.argmax(quality_pred)],end='')
  print("\t Predict rotation:" ,rotate_labels[np.argmax(rotate_pred)], ", p:", rotate_pred[np.argmax(rotate_pred)],end='')
  
  print()
  if y is not None:
    q_l = quality_labels[y[0]]
    r_l = rotate_labels[y[1]]
    b_l = bgr_labels[y[2]]
    print("True BGR or RGB:", b_l)
    print("True quality:", q_l)
    print("True rotation:" ,r_l)
  print()
  print()
```

Comment: it just makes a few steps

Comment: How? could you provide a screenshot?